# Output of ftp command not redirecting to file

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a process that transfers multiple files from Windows Server 2016 to an FTP site. Every hour a Scheduled Task runs a batch script to make this happen.

The original code in the batch script was as follows

```
@echo off
echo user username > ftpcmd.dat
echo password >> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin >> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd private/DirA >> ftpcmd.dat
echo put "D:\Data\Export\FileA.csv" >> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit >> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat my.address.co.uk
del ftpcmd.dat

@echo off
echo user username > ftpcmd.dat
echo password >> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin >> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd private/DirB >> ftpcmd.dat
echo put "D:\Data\Export\FileB.csv" >> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit >> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat my.address.co.uk
del ftpcmd.dat

cd /d D:\Data\Export\
del *.csv
```

This code works. However I need a log of the FTP upload, so I thought adding "`> log.txt`" and "`>> log.txt`" to the ftp commands would give me that. The new batch file is

```
@echo off
echo user username > ftpcmd.dat
echo password >> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin >> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd private/DirA >> ftpcmd.dat
echo put "D:\Data\Export\FileA.csv" >> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit >> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat my.address.co.uk > log.txt
del ftpcmd.dat

@echo off
echo user username > ftpcmd.dat
echo password >> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin >> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd private/DirB >> ftpcmd.dat
echo put "D:\Data\Export\FileB.csv" >> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit >> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat my.address.co.uk >> log.txt
del ftpcmd.dat

cd /d D:\Data\Export\
del *.csv
```

This does not work. It doesn't produce a log file and doesn't upload either file (though it does delete the csv files from the folder at the end).

It's also worth noting that running the batch file directly (simply double-clicking it) uploads the files and creates log.txt, but when run from the Task Scheduler it fails.

I've checked permissions and the Task is set to run using my user account (i.e. the account I have tested the batch file with), indeed it runs fine as long as there isn't a log file being output.

Any ideas on what to check next? Or is there another way of getting a log of the ftp conversation? Perhaps writing it to a variable and outputting the variable at the end of the script?

I'm happy to move the question to Server Fault if it's more appropriate there.

Comment: Going to assume your scheduled task is configured to run even when the user is not logged in. This sets the working directory to system32. You need to specify the full path to where you want the log file written. Or if you want it in the same folder as the batch file use %~dp0.

Comment: Side note. You can upload both files with one ftp step. No need to do two.

Comment: Yes, you're right, task is set to "Run whether user is logged on or not". That's interesting, I'll try it with a full path now. However, I was wondering why the ftpcmd.dat file works with a relative path? I thought about a full path but assumed that since ftpcmd.dat didn't need one then the log wouldn't either

Comment: Thanks for the side note - I've inherited this code from a previous developer so I didn't want to mess about with it too much. But I might look into that too

Comment: Wonderful. Just tried and it worked first time. Thanks so much. If you want to add an answer to this question I'll happily mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Your ftp command is changing directory on the ftp server.